# How to remove a space generated after using \cline in tabular?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am using `tabularx` in Springer nature template. I want to create a table, but the problem is that after I am using `\cline{2-2}`, the created table generated with a space. I want to remove this space. What I should do ?

I tried use `\cmidule` and `\cline` but the same problem.
This is the code :

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  % (don't know how '\processtable' is defined, hence commented out:)
  % \processtable{Comparison of performance indices for different cases}
  \label{Table2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c| cccc| @{}|}     \hline 
             &  A   & B    & C    & D \\ \hline
             & 0.5  & 0.01 & 0.29 & I \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
       p = 2 & 0.56 & 4.7  & 2.7  & J \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
             & 8.2  & 2.6  & 1.4  & K \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

And this is the template of the work: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of your code?

Comment: Showed gap is not caused by `\cline{2-2` You probably use `\cmidrule{2-2}` (defined in `booktabs`), however this is just guessing since your code is unknow, Consequently no one can help you.

Comment: as Zarko says you will not get the output that you show using `\cline`  If you are using `booktabs` then see the rule in the booktabs manual about use of vertical rules.

Comment: @Zarko I tried \Cmidule{2-2] but the same problem

Comment: Where is defined `\Cmidrule`? You left us to guessing (since our crystal ball are fogy ;-)  and we cant see in them what you doing). Please, provide complete small document (Minimal Working Example) inserted in your question, which reproduce your problem. Help us to help you.

Comment: You have still not provided an example that shows the problem I don't know any package that defines `\Cmidrule` so can't comment on that but if you are using booktabs `\cmidrule` then like all booktabs commands it is incompatible with vertical rules by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably respect the style of the tabulars of your journal, which is to do tabulars without vertical rules.

Moreover, if you use `\cmidrule`, you are using tools of `booktabs` and that package provides tools to construct tabulars without vertical rules.

However, if you actually want to use vertical rules with the command `\cmidrule` of `booktabs`, you can try the package `nicematrix`. In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of that package (similar to `{tabular}`), the vertical rules are never broken.

However, in order to use `nicematrix` with the class `sn-jnl`, you have to load `pgf` (which is a sub-layer of Tikz) before the `\documentclass`.

```
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
```

Moreover, you need the latest version of `nicematrix`. However, Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

```
\RequirePackage{pgf}
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \label{Table2}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}|c| cccc| @{}|}     \hline 
             &  A   & B    & C    & D \\ \hline
             & 0.5  & 0.01 & 0.29 & I \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
       p = 2 & 0.56 & 4.7  & 2.7  & J \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
             & 8.2  & 2.6  & 1.4  & K \\ \hline 
    \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

If I complete your fragment to an example document it produces

[image]

Note that `\cline` as used in the first table does not break the vertical rules (despite the title of this question).

The `booktabs` command `\cmidrule` like all `booktabs` commands is designed for tables without vertical rules. The booktabs manual is quite explicit about the use of `|` and vertical rules, specifying:

> Never, ever use vertical rules.